# ASP migration to .net 6 tools

Tags: .net-6.0, code-migration

I've been asked to take an existing fairly large (150 page) database driven site that was written in ASP classic and upgrade it to .net 5 or .net 6.
Are there any reliable tools available to make this process not a nightmare?
Would a complete rewrite in .net 5/6 or php be a better solution?

Comment: I get why you would want to go .net for the bi-directional server access so you don't have to submit a page each time you want the back and forth of data exchange.  But isn't php the same way as classic-asp as in single directional though?  Or is it more about not adding function and more about you know .net and php better?  And if so, might as well go .net to save a future coder from converting it from php to .net one day.

Comment: There could be pages where it takes like 3 or 4 pages just to pass data from one place to another, so if you go .net there might be ways to consolidate the re-write a bit so that 150 pages might really only be 100 or something like that.  Such as a form, to a review, to then a process page, where some of those could be the same page in a bi-directional situation where you can pass data without having to navigate or refresh.